# Using PHP simple dom parser with instagram

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to make a little tool which scrape the pictures of an instagram account using [PHP simple dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

However when I try to extract content using the parser I get a blank page. Is there anyway to make it work with instagram ?

```
require 'simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php'; 


// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('https://www.instagram.com/techcrunch/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram public RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747870/instagram-public-rss-feed)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of https://www.instagram.com/techcrunch/ you'll see that it has no `<img>` tags in it. These are created later by JavaScript.

Using the [official instagram APIs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent) might be a better option.

There are [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433032/1385572), but they are a bit hackish and may stop working at any time.